# In .NET Core force package to use my version of dll

Tags: .net-core, blazor, webassembly

I have the nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly` that depends on the dll
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.dll`. I also have a custom version of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.dll`.

Is it possible to force my project to use only my version of the dll?

Adding a reference to my `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.dll` in the project does not work.

Comment: It's not clear what do you mean by `does not work`.

Comment: Another question: how will you be using it in CI/CD? Doesn't sound like a good idea to hack ASP.NET Core libraries. Why did you make a custom version of it?

Comment: does not work = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly is still loading the old dll from the dependency on the package

Comment: I've compiled the asp.net core source and took the dll i wanted. If possible i would like very much not having to create nuget packges of all aspnetcore